# Howto to upload images from mobile and manage them with Nativescript/Nodejs Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, mobile, nativescript

I would like to upload images from Mobile device in Nativescript/Nodejs.

-I'm using MySql as Database
-I would like for example, that User add images (User profile picture, or other pictures) from Mobile library or took in live by Mobile camera and after images are uploaded, they must go to a files share and save their metadata in Database.
-Then according to the mobile OS (android or Iphone) and to the mobile/device dimensions (phone or tablet) the right image size must be shown while trying to read the images.

Can somebody help please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can base64 encode your image and send it.  See here:  https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/how-to-base64-encode-a-string-in-nativescript/345  Then you can decode the string and save it to a fileshare and save the metadata to the database along with image filename.

I am not sure if the metadata is available on decode.  If not you can get the metadata using a  plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-media-metadata-retriever